# Remove broken/ nonexistent font in IDEA 2016?

Tags: intellij-idea

The mononoki font has been deleted, the IDEA 2016 Ccommunity edition still show the font  in setting as show in the following screenshot, so how can I remove the font name in setting? reintstallation is useless, I have removed everything about IDEA after uninstall and reinstall it，nothing helped。
OS：win 10
also I cannot found the IDEA built-in font directory.

[image]

Comment: What OS do you use? Are you sure this font is not present in the system and in the JDK used to run IDEA?

Comment: @CrazyCoder the OS is win 10 Home edition, the font has been deleted from %windir%fonts, and also I am sure I cannot find it in office software. I cannot find the IDEA's font directory, not in openjdk's JRE, the only fonts I can find is in android plugin.

Comment: So, if you run [this code](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform) on the [same Java](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) as used by IntelliJ IDEA, you don't see `mononoki` font in the list?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I run the code on Oracle JDK(the IDEA is run on openjdk), the result contains `mononoki`, so how to fix it? I cannot see the font file in  Windows/fonts folder, thanks!

Comment: OK, the problem has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA then. Could be a [font cache](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-rebuild-a-font-cache).